# Storage Format for AND-OR-tree in Python 2.7

Tags: python, python-2.7, tree, decision-tree

I am doing some work with decision trees at the moment, where I am using AND-OR trees as representation. I am looking for a suitable storage format for these kind of trees.

The node which starts with "t" is an OR node, the node starts with a "c" is an (ordered!) AND node. The leaves always start with "p".

Originally, every node contains of two parts: a node name and a node description.

The pictures showing two different representation of the same decision tree. Basically I need both representation, respectively an easy and fast solution to convert the representations to each other.
[image]
[image]

**My thoughts so far**

*Datatype:*

Dict: It would be necessary to use the ordered dict. In addition, it would be easier to store the name and the description.

Lists would be good because the order is defined, however I don't know how to save the node name and description in a good way.

*Node link:*

Basically, it would be possible to use both kind of datatypes. However I don't know how to link the nodes to each other. Should I use keyword (such as "AND" and "OR") or should I nest the nodes?

Would be very thankful for any input.

Comment: "Dict: The order within a dict is not defined": there's an OrderedDict in the standard library https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict

Comment: Sorry, I totally forgot about that. You are right. I added this to my question.
Even there is the possibility for an ordered dict, the question is, whether it makes sense to use a dict.

I added, that I am looking for a solution in python 2.7

Comment: You can also create your custom class with fields name, type, description, list of descendant nodes and if nessesary reference to parent node. However I believe it won't be computationally efficient if it is important.

Answer (score 0):

If you use lists, you can link them together by nesting.
Something like:

```
['t1', ['c1', 'p1', ['c2', 'p2', 'p3']], ['c3', ['c4', 'p4', 'p5'], ['t2', ['c5', 'p6', 'p7'], 'p8']]]
```

The basic structure would be:

```
BASE := [node_name, left, right]
```

where:

- `node_name` is (in this example) a string and
- `left` and `right` are
  either a `BASE` (which implicitly means they are either a `c` or `t`
  type of node) or a `node name` (which implicitly means they are leaf
  nodes)

Nothing stops you from using `OrderedDict`s but the creation gets a bit more cumbersome IMO:

```
In [26]: from collections import OrderedDict as OD

In [27]: tree = OD((('name', 't1'), ('left', 'c1'), ('right', OD((('name', '...'),)) )))

In [28]: tree
Out[28]: 
OrderedDict([('name', 't1'),
             ('left', 'c1'),
             ('right', OrderedDict([('name', '...')]))])
```

Finally, you can just create your own data structure:

```
class Node:
     type = ''
     left = None
     right = None
```